# using weak qualifier for variable in a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

```
- (void)showWeakValue
{
    NSString * __weak weakString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"First Name: AA"];
    NSNumber * __weak weakNum = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:10];
    NSLog(@"weakString =  %@", weakString);
    NSLog(@"weakNum  = %@",weakNum);
}
```

the output is

```
 weakString =  (null)
 weakNum  = 10
```

why is weakNum not null? because there's no other strong reference to weakNum, it should be deallocated immediately after assignment. right?

Answer (score 4):

<s>I think either `weakNum` is deallocated immediately (as expected) and your code then invokes **undefined behavior,** or `NSNumber` is making tricky optimizations and you get back a singleton which always holds the value 10 and is alive throughout the lifetime of the program.</s>

**Edit: aham, huh, nope.** I just logged the pointer itself using

```
NSLog(@"weakNum pointer: %016llx", (uint64_t)weakNum);
```

and got

```
weakNum pointer: 000000000003e883
```

Now that's weird. A pointer-to-struct which is not 16 byte-aligned? So this is a **[tagged pointer](http://objectivistc.tumblr.com/post/7872364181/tagged-pointers-and-fast-pathed-cfnumber-integers-in).**

Let's analyze the pointer value! The 0th (LSB) bit is set, that's clear - that indicates the tagged pointer.

The 1st bit is set too: according to the reference behind the link, that's the tagged object class for integers. That matches our expectations. That's the 0th nibble.

Then in the next (1st) nibble, i. e. bits 4...7, we have the value 8, which is binary `100`, for which the quoted reference says `0100 for 16-bit integers`. That's exact, 1000 doesn't fit into 8 bits, but it does fit into 16 bits.

And then what do we have next? `3e8`, which is the hexadecimal for decimal 1000.

So, we've proved that this is a tagged pointer - at least on the system I tested this on (OS X 10.7.5 64-bit).

Comment: In http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.18/CFInternal.h you can see that tagged pointers are used on 64-bit only. So your answer applies to OS X and mine to iOS :-)

Answer (score 4):

`NSNumber` is toll-free bridged to `CFNumber`, which is open source.
From http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.19/CFNumber.c
you can see that `NSNumber` *caches* the created objects for integer values between 
(-1) and 12, so that the object returned by

```
[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:10]
```

is never deallocated, and multiple calls return the same instance.

For

```
[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1000]
```

you will probably see a different behaviour.

Comment: Still works for 1000 on my machine (OS X 10.7.5), maybe it's just tagged pointers after all?

Comment: @H2CO3: I *think* that tagged pointers are used only in the 64-bit environment, so it could be different between iOS and OS X. But I do not have a concrete reference at the moment.

Comment: I've found that and I'm updating my answer.

Comment: I don't think "toll-free bridged" implies that the NS and CF share the same internal implementation. I know for a fact that this is not the case for dictionaries and streams.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: I am sure that you are generally right, but in this particular case, the small test `int i = 10; NSNumber *num = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:i]; CFNumberRef cnum = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberIntType, &i);` shows (on iOS) that both calls return *identical* pointers. - Anyway, this are all implementation details and of course one should not rely on that behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, I wished Foundation were OpenSource  ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper It does imply that. They have the very same memory layout and are interoperable (why do you think the "C-only" CoreFoundation API links against the Objective-C runtime? It's evil hackage, but apparently it works.)

Comment: I meant, if there are corresponding CF and NS classes which are "toll-free bridged", this does not automatically mean they share the same implementation from the CF sources. Usually, these classes *behave* the *same* or have very strong similarities. Nonetheless, there *can* be huge differences in edge cases, in not so obvious aspects like performance or memory footprint. Thus, one must just be careful when looking into the sources of CF pendants when drawing assumptions how the NS class internally works. Hence, I would love to see Foundation as OpenSource ;)